# Given a CDF find the PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $$F(x) = 1 − \Bbb e ^{-x^3}; x > 0$$ be the cumulative distribution
function of a continuous random variable $X$.

(a) Find the probability density function of $X$.

(b) Find the value of $c$ such that $P(X < c) = 0.5$.

For (a), do I just take the derivative of $F(x)$ to find $f(x)$?
(in which case the pdf is $3x^2e^{-x^3}$ )

I haven't tried for (b) since I'm not sure on (a).

Comment: a) is correct! Any ideas on b)?

Comment: as I understand the problem, c can take on any value greater then $1/2$ since $P(X<c) = 1/2$

Comment: $\int_0^c 3x^2e^{-x^3} dx=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, but you better check the definition of a cdf, this is $F(c)=P(X\le c)$

Comment: this is what I show in my notes: $$ P(X <c) = F(c) − lim F(x).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Indeed, the probability density function of $X$ can be obtained by differentiating the cumulative distribution of $X$. So your answer $f(x)=F'(x)=3x^2e^{-x^3}$ is correct.

(b) Here you simply use the definition of cumulative distribution function, $P(X<c)=F(c)$, so
\begin{eqnarray}
0.5 &=& F(c) = 1-e^{-c^3}\\
e^{-c^3}&=&1/2 \\
c &=& (\ln2)^{1/3}
\end{eqnarray}